# print toString() from another class

Tags: java

I asked a question earlier on this same project but I'm still having issues that I can't get through. 
The project has a Person class, Validator class, Customer class, and Employee class. The Person class stores data about the person (name, email) the Customer class extends the person class and adds a customer number to the toString method. The Employee class also extends the Person class and extends a social security number to the toString method by overriding it.

At the bottom of the page I am trying to print the toString methods from my customer class OR my employee class. I want to make sure I am printing the right class based on what the user selected (if they are entering customer info or employee info)

The assignment specifically says "To print the data for an object to the console, this application should use a static method named print that accepts a Person object."

I think I have it started but I'm getting all kinds of red lines under what I have coded. Starting around the

```
    public void toString()
```

line down towards the bottom.

I'm starting to think I am getting deeper into trouble by looking it up online so if someone can help me through it I would be greatful. My book doesn't show much on how to do this and all of the examples it shows seem to create the input and then print it but I'm trying to get the input from a user so I'm getting confused.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class PersonApp 
    {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //welcome user to person tester
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Person Tester Application");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    //set choice to y
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        //prompt user to enter customer or employee
        System.out.println("Create customer or employee (c/e): ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {
            String firstName = Validator.getString(in, "Enter first name: ");
            String lastName = Validator.getString(in, "Enter last name: ");
            String email = Validator.getEmail(in, "Enter email address: ");
            String custNumber = Validator.getString(in, "Customer number: ");
            Customer customer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, email, custNumber);


        }

        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
        {
            String firstName = Validator.getString(in, "Enter first name: ");
            String lastName = Validator.getString(in, "Enter last name: ");
            String email = Validator.getEmail(in, "Enter email address: ");
            int empSoc = Validator.getInt(in, "Social security number: ");
            Employee employee = new Employee(firstName, lastName, email, empSoc);
        }

    public void toString()
    {
        Person p;
        p = c;
        System.out.println(c.toString());

        p = e;
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("Continue? y/n: ");
    choice = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println();


}
}
    }
```

Comment: toString returns a String, not void.  The tooltip on the 'red text' should give you an idea what is wrong most of the time.

Comment: I agree, you are messing things up by copying code from the internet when its clear you don't understand it. In this case the bigger problem is you are pasting the code for a method `toString` in the middle of another (`main`). That code is also useless. You should go back and go one step at a time.

Comment: @madth3 I actually coded that part myself and then when it wasn't working I started searching the internet for help. I don't know that is much better but at least I can say I screwed it all up on my own LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define methods inside another method.  The way you have the brackets, `toString` is defined inside `main`, which is illegal.

Also, you can't have `toString` return `void`, since it overrides the `toString` method from `Object`.  Rename your method or have it return a `String`.

Comment: so do I move the method below my "continue y/n?" statement? Will it still print the method?

Comment: You need to move it outside of the main method, and you need to call it, like you would any other method.

Comment: I'm having another issue. I have a line in that toString method that declares Person p; this looks good but I want Customer c; and Employee e; When I type those two I get red lines and it is telling me to create a local variable. What I'm attempting to do is tell the program if the user entered C to put in customer info I want it to print the Customer toString. The same with e for Employee. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: You'll have to pass a `Customer` or `Employee` to your `toString` method, or create `toString` methods for each one independently.  How you do that is your call.

Answer (score 0):

Your toString method needs to be moved out of your main method. It also needs to return a string. You'll probably have to call the method by some other name. Also, if Employee and Validator are in a separate package structure, you'll have to import that